# How to build a jqueryui theme for previous versions of jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui

On a project I can't use jqueryui 1.9 because of jquery version (1.4)

Is there a way to build a custom theme for jqueryui 1.8 ?

Comment: It's just CSS, you can do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to access it through http://ui-dev.jquery.com/themeroller/, you can even build a theme for 1.7.3 when download.

Comment: Updated & fixed the link. jqueryui seems to updated their subdomain.